# How to install Clang 11 on Debian

Tags: c++, linux, debian, clang, gnu

I am trying to compile a C++ project on a PC with "Debian GNU/Linux 10". The project requires clang, so I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

But I run into the following error:

```
Clang version must be at least 11, the version used is 7.0.1
```

How can I install clang 11?

Note: I do not want to install the entire LLVM package again. Just want to upgrade Clang from version 7 to 11, preferably via command-line.

Comment: Install package clang-11 (you may need to add testing or unstable to your source.list). Or upgrade to debian 11.

Comment: You cannot "just upgrade clang", it will necessarily come with some other pieces of llvm.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution after some searching. Here is what I did to make it work:

1. Add the following lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster main 
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster main 
deb http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-10 main 
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-10 main 
deb http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-11 main 
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/buster/ llvm-toolchain-buster-11 main
```

2. Add signatures for these repos (otherwise apt-get update will complain in the next step)

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

3. Run apt-get update to add these new repos to the apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

4. Install clang-11:

```
sudo apt-get install clang-11
```

5. Make sure now "clang-11" is used by the compiler and not the older "clang":

```
export CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-11
export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-11
```

6. Compile your project.
7. Enjoy!

For documentation: https://apt.llvm.org/

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest installing the latest stable 15

1. Add the following lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye main
# 15
deb http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye-15 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bullseye/ llvm-toolchain-bullseye-15 main
```

2. Add signatures for these repos (otherwise apt-get update will complain in the next step)

```
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

3. Run apt-get update to add these new repos to the apt-get:

```
 sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

4. To install all key packages

```
sudo apt-get install libllvm-15-ocaml-dev libllvm15 llvm-15 llvm-15-dev llvm-15-doc llvm-15-examples llvm-15-runtime
```

5. Install clang-15

```
 sudo apt-get install clang-15 lldb-15 lld-15
```

6. Make sure now "clang-15" is used by the compiler and not the older "clang" and done just compile your project

```
export CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-15

export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-15
```

Doc https://apt.llvm.org/