# Instructions for installing latest version of Node (v20) on Ubuntu in Docker not working?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I just followed the instructions to install the latest version of Node (v20) on Ubuntu in docker, with this in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install imagemagick
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:fontforge/fontforge
RUN apt-get -y install fontforge
RUN apt-get -y install pandoc
RUN apt-get -y install texlive
RUN apt-get -y install ffmpeg
RUN apt-get -y install rar
RUN apt-get -y install inkscape
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN apt-get -y install libreoffice
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get -y install npm
RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"
```

Then I run this to get at the CLI prompt:

```
docker exec -it mycontainer sh
```

And I see:

```
$ node -v
v12.22.9
```

What is wrong? It should say it shows Node.js v20.x.

```
=> CACHED [13/21] RUN apt-get -y install libreoffice                      0.0s
=> CACHED [14/21] RUN apt-get upgrade                                     0.0s
=> CACHED [15/21] RUN apt-get -y install curl                             0.0s
=> CACHED [16/21] RUN apt-get -y install gnupg                            0.0s
=> [17/21] RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x  | bash -   4.4s
=> [18/21] RUN apt-get -y install nodejs                                  6.0s
=> [19/21] RUN apt-get -y install npm                                    47.6s
=> [20/21] RUN npm install -g pnpm                                        2.1s
=> [21/21] RUN bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"        0.1s
=> exporting to image                                                     0.6s
=> => exporting layers                                                    0.6s
=> => writing image sha256:4cc27be37abd8828eef72b14d3c3f558e1f2f817dca03  0.0s
=> => naming to docker.io/myorg/myimage                                   0.0s

What's Next?
  View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview

$ docker exec -it mycontainer sh

# node -v
v12.22.9
```

Comment: Whose instructions? Why not _start_ with a Node container: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/tags?page=1&name=20

Comment: I need to install a specific version of platform linux/amd64 and the node images don't support that I don't think. For render.com. Here are instructions similar to what I did https://www.sitepoint.com/install-node-js-on-ubuntu/.

Comment: Why do you think they don't? You can see from the above link that they _do_ support that arch. Here's the first: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/node/20.10.0-bullseye/images/sha256-8041e38bd6bf93d476694aac10c788e4ec3bd155d3e3f751dabd58a3eb35e3a1?context=explore&tab=vulnerabilities. And why just  something _similar_?!

Comment: That is debian, how do I find a latest ubuntu node 20 that supports that arch?

Comment: @jonrsharpe still, it doesn't solve the question, but it may work...

Comment: Yes, I think they build on Debian and Alpine - https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1677. Why if at all does Ubuntu matter, specifically?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the packages, specifically libreoffice, fontforge, and pandoc don't work well on debian, or are otherwise not available. They work on ubuntu is all I know.

Comment: That's all useful context to put in the question, with a [mre] (even if the packages are the motivation for Ubuntu, does sitting through their install actually help recreate the issue - unless one of them depends on the wrong Node).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with my deps by switching to Debian as the commenter pointed out.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:20.10.0-bullseye
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install imagemagick
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN apt-get -y install fontforge
RUN apt-get -y install pandoc
RUN apt-get -y install texlive
RUN apt-get -y install ffmpeg
RUN apt-get -y install libarchive-tools
RUN apt-get -y install inkscape
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN apt-get -y install libreoffice
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install gnupg
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# LLVM prereqs
RUN apt-get -qq update; \
    apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
        gnupg2 wget ca-certificates apt-transport-https \
        autoconf automake cmake dpkg-dev file make patch libc6-dev

# Install LLVM
COPY llvm.txt .
RUN cat llvm.txt > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm.list && \
    wget -qO /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/llvm.asc \
        https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key && \
    apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get install -qqy -t bullseye clang-17 clang-tidy-17 clang-format-17 libc++-17-dev libc++abi-17-dev && \
    for f in /usr/lib/llvm-*/bin/*; do ln -sf "$f" /usr/bin; done && \
    ln -sf clang /usr/bin/cc && \
    ln -sf clang /usr/bin/c89 && \
    ln -sf clang /usr/bin/c99 && \
    ln -sf clang++ /usr/bin/c++ && \
    ln -sf clang++ /usr/bin/g++ && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

LLVM wasn't as easy to install on debian, but hey.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/llvm ?

Comment: @DavidMaze While it "installs", it doesn't work, I get `clang not found`. Hence https://stackoverflow.com/a/66227796/169992.